# Weird floating behaviour

Tags: html, css, floating

I have a floating problem on my Website.

I have 6 Div container, 3 for in every row and all floated left.
So it should be like:

0-0-0

0-0-0

but instead its like:

0-0-0

----0

0-0

Here is a link problem:

[Website](http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=101)

```css
    #container {
     float: left;
     margin: 0 -240px 0 0;
     width: 100%;
    }

    #primary,
    #secondary {
     float: right;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 220px;
    }
    #secondary {
     clear: right;
    }
    #footer {
     clear: both;
     width: 100%;
    }



    /* =Structure
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /* The main theme structure */
    #access .menu-header,
    div.menu,
    #colophon,
    #branding,
    #main,
    #wrapper {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 1000px;
    }
    #wrapper {
     margin-top: 20px;
     padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    }

    /* Structure the footer area */
    #footer-widget-area {
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    #footer-widget-area .widget-area {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 20px;
     width: 220px;
    }
    #footer-widget-area #fourth {
     margin-right: 0;
    }
    #site-info {
     float: left;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     width: 700px;
    }
    #site-generator {
     float: right;
     width: 220px;
    }



    /* Infobox */


    .infotext {
     width:600px;
     margin: 80px 0 0 500px;
     
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }


    /* Overview */

    .child-thumb {
     width: 282px;
     float:left;
     margin: 15px;
       background: #CCC;
    }

    .child-thumb p a {
     display: none;
    }

    .wp-post-image {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .bilderrahmen-wrapper {
     z-index: 1;
     height: 220px;
     width: 290px;
     overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-animation: childthumb 5s ease-in-out infinite;
     animation: childthumb 5s ease-in-out infinite;
     transform-origin: 50% -30%;
     transform: translateZ(0);
     
    }

    .bilderrahmen {
     z-index: 1;
     height: 175px;
     width: 290px;
     background: url(image/overview.png);
     overflow: hidden;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .plakette_wrapper {
     text-align: center;
    }

    .plakette {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 53px;
     margin: -20px 0 0 0;
    }

    .plakette span {
     background: url(image/plakette/middle.png);
     height: 53px;
     float: left !important;
     line-height: 49px;
     color: #272727;
     margin-left: -1px;
    }

    .plakette .left {
     float: left;
     background: url(image/plakette/left.png);
     height: 53px;
     width: 31px;
    }
    .plakette .right {
     float: left;
     background: url(image/plakette/right.png);
     height: 53px;
     width: 34px;
     margin-left: -1px;
    }







    .bilderrahmen-wrapper .thumb {
     z-index: -1;
     height: 135px;
     width: 265px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     margin: -166px 0 0 9px;
    }

    .thumb-image {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .child-thumb a {
     text-decoration: none !important;
    }



    .child-thumb p {
     margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    }


    /* This is the custom header image */
    #branding img {
     border-top: 4px solid #000;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     display: block;
     float: left;
    }

    .logo {
     height:154px;
     width:146px;
     background:url(images/logo.png);
     display:block;
     float:left;
     margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
    }


    /* =Menu
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    #access {
     display: block;
     float: right;
     margin: 85px 20px 0 0;
     width: 775px;
     
    }
    #access .menu-header,
    div.menu {
     font-size: 18px;
     margin-left: 12px;
     width: 928px;
    }
    #access .menu-header ul,
    div.menu ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
    }
    #access .menu-header li,
    div.menu li {
     float: left;
     padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
     position: relative;
    }
    #access a {
     color: #191919;
     display: block;
     line-height: 38px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform:uppercase;
     font-weight:100;
     font-family: 'Delius Unicase', cursive !important;
    }
    #access ul ul {
     position:absolute;
        top:-99999px;
        left:0;
        opacity: 0; /* Hide sub level */
        -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        z-index:497;
    }
    #access ul ul li {
     min-width: 180px;
    }
    #access ul ul ul {
     left: 100%;
     top: 0;
    }
    #access ul ul a {
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
     line-height: 1em;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 220px;
     height: auto;
     
    }
    #access li:hover > a,
    #access ul ul :hover > a {
     color: #ea4f23 !important;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
        -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
        -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
        -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
        transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    }

    #access a {
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
        -kthtml-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
     }
     
    #access ul li:hover > ul {
     opacity: 1; position:absolute; top:99%; left:0; z-index: 1000;
     
    }
    #access ul li.current_page_item > a,
    #access ul li.current_page_ancestor > a,
    #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
    #access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
    #access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
     color: #454545;
    }
    * html #access ul li.current_page_item a,
    * html #access ul li.current_page_ancestor a,
    * html #access ul li.current-menu-ancestor a,
    * html #access ul li.current-menu-item a,
    * html #access ul li.current-menu-parent a,
    * html #access ul li a:hover {
     color: #454545;
    }


    /* =Content
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    #home-container {
     height:200px;
     width: 1200px;
     margin:680px 0 0 0;
    }

    #main {
     clear: both;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 32px 30px 30px 30px;
     background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);;
     position: relative;
     min-height: 700px;
     background: url(images/bg-content.png)
    }

    .main-top {
     background: url(images/bg-content-top.png);
     height: 13px;
     width: 1000px;
     margin: -45px 0 0 0;
    }

    .main-bottom {
     background: url(images/bg-content-bottom.png);
     height: 13px;
     width: 1000px;
     margin-top: -10px;
    }

    #content {
     margin: 0px 0 36px 0;
    }

    .entry-content {
     -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 3;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        widows:5;
    }



    #content,
    #content input,
    #content textarea {
     color: #333;
     font-size: 15px;
     line-height: 24px;
    }
    #content p,
    #content ul,
    #content ol,
    #content dd,
    #content pre,
    #content hr {
     margin-bottom: 24px;
    }
    #content ul ul,
    #content ol ol,
    #content ul ol,
    #content ol ul {
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #content pre,
    #content kbd,
    #content tt,
    #content var {
     font-size: 15px;
     line-height: 21px;
    }
    #content code {
     font-size: 13px;
    }
    #content dt,
    #content th {
     color: #000;
    }
    #content h1,
    #content h2,
    #content h3,
    #content h4,
    #content h5,
    #content h6 {
     color: #000;
     line-height: 1.5em;
     margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    }
    #content table {
     border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
     margin: 0 -1px 24px 0;
     text-align: left;
     width: 100%;
    }
    #content tr th,
    #content thead th {
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 18px;
     padding: 9px 24px;
    }
    #content tr td {
     border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
     padding: 6px 24px;
    }
    #content tr.odd td {
     background: #f2f7fc;
    }
    .hentry {
     margin: 0 0 48px 0;
    }
    .home .sticky {
     background: #f2f7fc;
     border-top: 4px solid #000;
     margin-left: -20px;
     margin-right: -20px;
     padding: 18px 20px;
    }
    .single .hentry {
     margin: 0 0 36px 0;
    }
    .page-title {
     color: #000;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 0 0 36px 0;
    }
    .page-title span {
     color: #333;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-style: italic;
     font-weight: normal;
    }
    .page-title a:link,
    .page-title a:visited {
     color: #777;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .page-title a:active,
    .page-title a:hover {
     color: #ff4b33;
    }
    #content .entry-title {
     color: #000;
     font-size: 21px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 1.3em;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .entry-title a:link,
    .entry-title a:visited {
     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .entry-title a:active,
    .entry-title a:hover {
     color: #ff4b33;
    }
    .entry-meta {
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    .entry-meta abbr,
    .entry-utility abbr {
     border: none;
    }
    .entry-meta abbr:hover,
    .entry-utility abbr:hover {
     border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    }
    .entry-content,
    .entry-summary {
     clear: both;
    }
    #content .entry-summary p:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .entry-content fieldset {
     border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
     margin: 0 0 24px 0;
     padding: 24px;
    }
    .entry-content fieldset legend {
     background: #fff;
     color: #000;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 0 24px;
    }
    .entry-content input {
     margin: 0 0 24px 0;
    }
    .entry-content input.file,
    .entry-content input.button {
     margin-right: 24px;
    }
    .entry-content label {
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
    }
    .entry-content select {
     margin: 0 0 24px 0;
    }
    .entry-content sup,
    .entry-content sub {
     font-size: 10px;
    }
    .entry-content blockquote.left {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 0;
     margin-right: 24px;
     text-align: right;
     width: 33%;
    }
    .entry-content blockquote.right {
     float: right;
     margin-left: 24px;
     margin-right: 0;
     text-align: left;
     width: 33%;
    }
    .page-link {
     clear: both;
     color: #000;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 48px;
     word-spacing: 0.5em;
    }
    .page-link a:link,
    .page-link a:visited {
     background: #f1f1f1;
     color: #333;
     font-weight: normal;
     padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .home .sticky .page-link a {
     background: #d9e8f7;
    }
    .page-link a:active,
    .page-link a:hover {
     color: #ff4b33;
    }
    body.page .edit-link {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
    }
    #entry-author-info {
     background: #f2f7fc;
     border-top: 4px solid #000;
     clear: both;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 20px;
     margin: 24px 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 18px 20px;
    }
    #entry-author-info #author-avatar {
     background: #fff;
     border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
     float: left;
     height: 60px;
     margin: 0 -104px 0 0;
     padding: 11px;
    }
    #entry-author-info #author-description {
     float: left;
     margin: 0 0 0 104px;
    }
    #entry-author-info h2 {
     color: #000;
     font-size: 100%;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .entry-utility {
     clear: both;
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 18px;
    }
    .entry-meta a,
    .entry-utility a {
     color: #777;
    }
    .entry-meta a:hover,
    .entry-utility a:hover {
     color: #ff4b33;
    }
    #content .video-player {
     padding: 0;
    }


    /* =Asides
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    .home #content .format-aside p,
    .home #content .category-asides p {
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-top: 0;
    }
    .home .hentry.format-aside,
    .home .hentry.category-asides {
     padding: 0;
    }
    .home #content .format-aside .entry-content,
    .home #content .category-asides .entry-content {
     padding-top: 0;
    }


    /* =Gallery listing
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    .format-gallery .size-thumbnail img,
    .category-gallery .size-thumbnail img {
     border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .format-gallery .gallery-thumb,
    .category-gallery .gallery-thumb {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 20px;
     margin-top: -4px;
    }
    .home #content .format-gallery .entry-utility,
    .home #content .category-gallery .entry-utility {
     padding-top: 4px;
    }


    /* =Attachment pages
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    .attachment .entry-content .entry-caption {
     font-size: 140%;
     margin-top: 24px;
    }
    .attachment .entry-content .nav-previous a:before {
     content: '\2190\00a0';
    }
    .attachment .entry-content .nav-next a:after {
     content: '\00a0\2192';
    }


    /* =Images
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /*
    Resize images to fit the main content area.
    - Applies only to images uploaded via WordPress by targeting size-* classes.
    - Other images will be left alone. Use "size-auto" class to apply to other images.
    */
    img.size-auto,
    img.size-full,
    img.size-large,
    img.size-medium,
    .attachment img,
    .widget-container img {
     max-width: 100%; /* When images are too wide for containing element, force them to fit. */
     height: auto; /* Override height to match resized width for correct aspect ratio. */
    }
    .alignleft,
    img.alignleft {
     display: inline;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 24px;
     margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .alignright,
    img.alignright {
     display: inline;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 24px;
     margin-top: 4px;
    }
    .aligncenter,
    img.aligncenter {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
    }
    img.alignleft,
    img.alignright,
    img.aligncenter {
     margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .wp-caption {
     background: #f1f1f1;
     line-height: 18px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     max-width: 632px !important; /* prevent too-wide images from breaking layout */
     padding: 4px;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .wp-caption img {
     margin: 5px 5px 0;
     max-width: 622px; /* caption width - 10px */
    }
    .wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
     margin: 5px;
    }
    .wp-smiley {
     margin: 0;
    }
    .gallery {
     margin: 0 auto 18px;
    }
    .gallery .gallery-item {
     float: left;
     margin-top: 0;
     text-align: center;
     width: 33%;
    }
    .gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item {
     width: 50%;
    }
    .gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
     width: 25%;
    }
    .gallery img {
     border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
    }
    .gallery-columns-2 .attachment-medium {
     max-width: 92%;
     height: auto;
    }
    .gallery-columns-4 .attachment-thumbnail {
     max-width: 84%;
     height: auto;
    }
    .gallery .gallery-caption {
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
     margin: 0 0 12px;
    }
    .gallery dl {
     margin: 0;
    }
    .gallery img {
     border: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
    }
    .gallery br+br {
     display: none;
    }
    #content .attachment img {/* single attachment images should be centered */
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }


    /* =Navigation
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */

    .navigation {
     color: #777;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 18px;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    .navigation a:link,
    .navigation a:visited {
     color: #777;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navigation a:active,
    .navigation a:hover {
     color: #ff4b33;
    }
    .nav-previous {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
    }
    .nav-next {
     float: right;
     text-align: right;
     width: 50%;
    }
    #nav-above {
     margin: 0 0 18px 0;
    }
    #nav-above {
     display: none;
    }
    .paged #nav-above,
    .single #nav-above {
     display: block;
    }
    #nav-below {
     margin: -18px 0 0 0;
    }


    .clear {
     clear: all;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">

        
        

     
    <div class="main-top"></div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="container" class="one-column">
       <div id="content" role="main">
       
       <div id="content-text">
           

        <div id="post-101" class="post-101 page type-page status-publish hentry">
               <h1 class="entry-title">Peeronauten</h1>
         
         <div class="entry-content">
          <p>Text fehlt.</p>
                     </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </div><!-- #post-## -->

        

       </div>
       
       
              <div class="child-thumb">
            <div class="bilderrahmen-wrapper">
             <div class="bilderrahmen"></div>
             <div class="thumb">
              <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=103"><img width="280" height="133" src="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/huber-300x143.jpg" class="thumb-image wp-post-image" alt="huber"></a>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="plakette_wrapper">
          <a class="plakette" href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=103">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span>Andreas Huber</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
          </a>     
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
                
           
               
               
                <p>Text fehlt. <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=103">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></p>
     
               
           </div>
                  <div class="child-thumb">
            <div class="bilderrahmen-wrapper">
             <div class="bilderrahmen"></div>
             <div class="thumb">
              <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=105"></a>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="plakette_wrapper">
          <a class="plakette" href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=105">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span>DMA</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
          </a>     
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
                
           
               
               
                <p>Die Veranstaltungstechniker eures Vertrauens und das Event eures Lebens! <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=105">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></p>
     
               
           </div>
                  <div class="child-thumb">
            <div class="bilderrahmen-wrapper">
             <div class="bilderrahmen"></div>
             <div class="thumb">
              <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=107"></a>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="plakette_wrapper">
          <a class="plakette" href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=107">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span>Nähatelier</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
          </a>     
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
                
           
               
               
                <p>Text fehlt. <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=107">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></p>
     
               
           </div>
                  <div class="child-thumb">
            <div class="bilderrahmen-wrapper">
             <div class="bilderrahmen"></div>
             <div class="thumb">
              <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=109"></a>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="plakette_wrapper">
          <a class="plakette" href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=109">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span>Studio23</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
          </a>     
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
                
           
               
               
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in neque ante.</p>
    <p> <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=109">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></p>
     
               
           </div>
                  <div class="child-thumb">
            <div class="bilderrahmen-wrapper">
             <div class="bilderrahmen"></div>
             <div class="thumb">
              <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=140"><img width="280" height="185" src="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/fechthut-300x199.jpg" class="thumb-image wp-post-image" alt="fechthut"></a>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="plakette_wrapper">
          <a class="plakette" href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=140">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span>Fecht-Hut</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
          </a>     
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
                
           
               
               
                <p>Westliche Kampfkunst lernen und erleben mit fast allen Waffen, die Klingen haben und mehr… denn der Westen hat einiges zu bieten.</p>
    <p> <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=140">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></p>
     
               
           </div>
                  <div class="child-thumb">
            <div class="bilderrahmen-wrapper">
             <div class="bilderrahmen"></div>
             <div class="thumb">
              <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=161"></a>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="plakette_wrapper">
          <a class="plakette" href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=161">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <span>Marky’s Schweisspalast</span>
            <div class="right"></div>
          </a>     
          </div>
          
          
         </div>
                
           
               
               
                <p>Text fehlt. <a href="http://philippdaub.de/peer23/?page_id=161">Weiterlesen <span class="meta-nav">→</span></a></p>
     
               
           </div>
              
       <div class="clear"></div>
       </div><!-- #content -->
      </div><!-- #container -->
    </div>
    <div class="main-bottom"></div>
     </div><!-- #main -->
```

Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: cute webzone. i like the pirates.

Comment: Like Mary (or quicker) said do this #content{font-size: 0px;}
And if those are keyframes animations, they kill my browser :(

Comment: I think the keyframe animations are making me seasick. I guess that is intended! :)

Comment: I'm glad you like it! Thanks :)

Comment: I dont what the heck you use for the pirate ship but it kiils my browser. İmprove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your css like the below to get a perfect output. Hope this helps!!!

```css
.child-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 282px;
}

#content {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: no issues!! thanks for the response!! Hope you've updated your site now!!

Comment: I can see one more issue in your site!! The content under the "child-thumbs" (bottom 3) are not visible properly!! To fix this, update your style.css (line-no. 1431) by removing the "height:30px" (atleast from the id "#content"

Answer (score 2):

You could solve the issue by doing the following.

**1** - Set `font-size: 0;` to the `#content`

**2** - Set `font-size:16px;`, `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:top;` to `.child-thumb`

**3** - Remove the `float: left;` to `.child-thumb`

Change you CSS like this:

```
#content {
    margin: 0px 0 36px 0;
    font-size: 0; /* font-size: 0; to remove the white-space between inline-block elements */
}
.child-thumb {
    width: 282px;
    /* float: left; */ /* remove the float: left; */
    margin: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; /* font-size: 16px; to reset the font-size to child elements */
    vertical-align: top; /* align inline-block elements to top */
}
```

I've tried to solve the issue using `float: left;` but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use firebug to detect your problem and I found the reason for your question.

```
Die Veranstaltungstechniker eures Vertrauens und das Event eures Lebens!
```

This sentence is too long to fit for the position.
There are two ways to fix your problem:

1. change above the sentence such as cutting it brief.
2. make the child `p` of the class `child-thumb` have unify height.